# Python datetime to XML Schema timestamp format

Tags: python, xml, xsd

Is there an easy way to create a timestamp, in XML Schema format?

`datetime.datetime.now()` does not work.

```
.now(): 2012-02-17 09:52:35.033232

Desired: 2012-02-15T14:18:46.295-02:00
```

Looks pretty much the same, but fails on schema validation.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc).isoformat()
'2012-02-17T11:58:44.789024+00:00'

>>> datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')).isoformat()
'2012-02-17T13:00:10.885743+01:00'
```

apply your own time zone if needed.

Comment: If some one need datetime object you can use some_date_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev')).isoformat()

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime